# cmd - modifying lines in a text file

Tags: windows, file, cmd, copy

I have the following text file:

```
c:/users/desktop
c:/users/test
c:/users/etc
....
```

Every line has one string in the text file. I want to modify the file so that every line has two strings. It should be like this:

```
c:/users/desktop c:/users/desktop
c:/users/test c:/users/test
c:/users/etc c:/users/etc
....
```

After this, I want to change the second string in each line such that it is a new path. There is a fixed `NEW_PATH` which contains the part that must be inserted. It would look like this after modification:

```
c:/users/desktop f:/etc/rel/users/desktop
c:/users/test f:/etc/rel/users/test
c:/users/etc f:/etc/rel/users/etc
```

I am trying to save this in an output file `tocopy.txt`.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a Windows platform, does it matter that / is used as the path separator rather than \? Using the string substitution expression is the key to making this change.

```
C:>TYPE tocopy.bat
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET EXITCODE=0

SET "OLDFILE=tocopy_source.txt"
SET "NEWFILE=tocopy.txt"
SET "OLDPATH=c:"
SET "NEWPATH=f:/etc/rel"

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%a IN (`TYPE "%OLDFILE%"`) DO (
    SET S1=%%a
    SET S2=!S1:%OLDPATH%=%NEWPATH%!
    ECHO %%a !S2!
)

EXIT /B %EXITCODE%

 8:39:26.37  C:\Users\pwatson\x
C:>TYPE tocopy_source.txt
c:/users/desktop
c:/users/test
c:/users/etc

C:>CALL tocopy.bat >tocopy.txt

C:>TYPE tocopy.txt
c:/users/desktop f:/etc/rel/users/desktop
c:/users/test f:/etc/rel/users/test
c:/users/etc f:/etc/rel/users/etc
```